Why only last photo can be deleted in forEach Loop?
The following codes are for displaying photos via forEach loop. And a delete button is put on the right top corner of each photo. If user doesn't like the photo, He/She can click the button to delete the photo. But in fact, only the delete button on the last photo can work. Other delete buttons can't work.  Why?
@State private var cards: [Card] = []
   
@State private var card: Card = Card(id:UUID(),photoData:Data())
        
ScrollView(.vertical) {
  VStack(spacing: 15) {
    /// Parallax Carousel
    GeometryReader(content: { geometry in
      let size = geometry.size

      ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        HStack(spacing: 5) {
          ForEach(cards) { card1 in
            GeometryReader(content: { proxy in
              let cardSize = proxy.size
              let minX = min((proxy.frame(in: .scrollView).minX - 30.0) * 1.4, size.width * 1.4)

              ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
                Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: card1.photoData) ?? UIImage(named: "photoForNil")!)
                  .resizable()
                  .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                  .offset(x: -minX)
                  .frame(width: proxy.size.width * 2.5)
                  .frame(width: cardSize.width, height: cardSize.height)
                  .clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: 15))
                  .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.25), radius: 8, x: 5, y: 10)

                Button {
                  cards.removeAll(where: {
                    $0.id == card1.id
                  })
                } label: {
                  Image(systemName: "multiply")
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
              }
            })
            .frame(width: size.width - 60, height: size.height - 50)
            .scrollTransition(.interactive, axis: .horizontal) { view, phase in
              view
                .scaleEffect(phase.isIdentity ? 1 : 0.95)
            }
          }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 30)
        .scrollTargetLayout()
        .frame(height: size.height, alignment: .top)
      }
      .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
      .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
    })
    .frame(height: 500)
    .padding(.horizontal, -15)
    .padding(.top, 10)
  }
}


The class for card is as following:
import SwiftUI

    ///Card Model
    struct Card: Identifiable, Hashable {
        var id: UUID = .init()
        var photoData: Data = Data()
        
        /// View Based Properties
        var scrollPosition: UUID?
    }


You should provide more complete and reproducible code, and at least a screenshot so we can understand what you're trying to do. As it is, there is no info about any variable models, types, etc.

Hi, Andrei, I add the class code in the post. It's really weird. It seems that in forEach loop, card1 can only represent the last item so array.removeAll can only work for the last one.

Thank you , but please revise the code some more and make sure it's complete. At the very least, it should be a complete struct so it can be copied, pasted and previewed elsewhere.

Hi, Andrei, Thank you for your reply. I haven't posted the whole struct because the lines of the codings for the whole struct are about 1 thousand. After two days' investigation, I found I have set some parameters for keeping the photos shifting too large. When I set them smaller, the delete buttons can work. I post the correct codes in the answer.

After two days' investigation, I found I have set some parameters for keeping the photos shifting too large. When I set them smaller, the delete buttons can work. I post the correct codes in the answer.
 ScrollView(.vertical) {
                        VStack(spacing: 15) {
                            /// Parallax Carousel
                            GeometryReader(content: { geometry in
                                let size = geometry.size
                                
                                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                                    HStack(spacing: 5) {
                                        ForEach(cards) { card1 in
                                            GeometryReader(content: { proxy in
                                                let cardSize = proxy.size
                                                let minX = min((proxy.frame(in: .scrollView).minX - 5.0) * 1.1, size.width * 1.1)
                                                
                                                ZStack(alignment:.topTrailing){
                                                    Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: card1.photoData) ?? UIImage(named: "photoForNil")!)
                                                        .resizable()
                                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                                        .offset(x: -minX)
                                                        .frame(width: proxy.size.width * 1.1)
                                                        .frame(width: cardSize.width, height: cardSize.height)
                                                        .clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: 15))
                                                        .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.25), radius: 8, x: 5, y: 10)
                                                    
                                                    Button{
                                                        cards = []
                                                        photoDatas = photoDatas.filter {
                                                            $0 != card1.photoData
                                                        }
                                                        for photodata in photoDatas {
                                                            card = Card(id:UUID(), photoData: photodata)
                                                            cards.append(card)
                                                        }
                                                    } label: {
                                                        Image(systemName: "multiply")
                                                            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                                                        .foregroundColor(.white)                            }
                                                }
                                            })
                                            .frame(width: size.width - 5, height: size.height - 5)
                                            .scrollTransition(.interactive, axis: .horizontal) { view, phase in
                                                view
                                                    .scaleEffect(phase.isIdentity ? 1 : 0.95)
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                                    .scrollTargetLayout()
                                    .frame(height: size.height, alignment: .top)
                                }
                                .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
                                .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
                            })
                            .frame(height: 500)
                            .padding(.horizontal, -5)
                            .padding(.top, 10)
                        }
                        .padding(5)
                    }
                    .scrollIndicators(.hidden)   

